# Why multiple files selected doesn't work on chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Following js code is for html5 multiple files selected [duplicate] that doesn't work for chrome browser, after selecting a file homonymous several times.

**For EX:** selecting file `admin.png` for 2 or up times tandem. It only alert for first times.

**DEMO (This doesn't work only in chrome browser ):** http://jsfiddle.net/s9mt4/

```
function doClick() {
    var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
    if (el) {
        el.click();
    }
}
function handleFiles(files) {
    var d = document.getElementById("fileList");

var elementArray = document.getElementsByClassName("ImgNameUp");
var ReValue = true;
for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; ++i){
    if(elementArray[i].innerHTML == files[0].name){
        ReValue = false;
    }
}
$('.ImgNameUp2').append('<div class="ImgNameUp">'+files[0].name+'</div>')
    if (ReValue) {
        alert('true');
    } else {
        alert('false');
    }
}
```

what do i do,change in code that it working right?

Comment: can you post your markup as well?

Comment: You say it doesn't work in chrome. Are you also saying that it *does* work in some other browser? or is chrome the only browser you are testing. the way it's written now, i would expect it to alert once, in every browser that supports multiple file select.

Comment: tested in firefox and it worked. this problem is in chrome

Comment: @kimsingh I have not been able to get this working in Firefox. The problem is definitely in the code.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that should cause two alerts, unless you change the value of the file input twice.

Comment: What is the problem code, and how to solve it out?

Comment: the problem is the code doesn't do what you want it to do... there isn't a problem with it at the moment. Logic error. You want it to alert twice, but you've only coded it to alert once.

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input fields are listening to the `onchange` event to fire the javascript.

According to [W3C's document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange):

> onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
>   value has been modified since gaining focus

if you try to upload the same file, the value of file input does not change so does not fire the function. I think Chrome is the only browser to implement this "correctly".

If you want to upload twice, clear file input value:

```
function doClick() {
    var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
    $(el).val(null); // <-- this line
    if (el) {
        el.click();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s9mt4/2/